# Accessing Raspberry PI from Ubuntu laptop

Tags: pi-3, ubuntu

I have bought raspberry pi 3 model b and want to access it from my laptop i have tried to connect pi to laptop using ethernet cable and my laptop is already connected to internet using my wifi but i am not able access it in anyway nor hdmi cable connection works what are the proper setup steps.

Is there a need to configure any network for it how to do that in ubuntu.

Comment: Have you flashed a micro SD card with Raspian and inserted it into the Pi? You need to do that before anything else.
[Here's a tutorial on basic setup from Adafruit.](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-raspberry-pi-lesson-1-preparing-and-sd-card-for-your-raspberry-pi)

Answer (score 0):

I would like to answer my own question as the major blogs all over the internet states to connect the pi to laptop using hdmi but it's not possible as laptop HDMI is HDMI out rather than  HDMI in so it will never work with laptop but if you've external monitor than you need to copy the image files of raspbian using dd command using `dd bs=1M` to improve the performance of PI and then you can attach monitor to initially configure ssh so that you can access it and change the configuration using `raspi-config` and so on.